# Handle/catch errors without repeating code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Consider the following (pseudo)function to update a database:

```
function my_function(req, res, input) {
  try {
    // This sanitizeInput() function throws error message if input is invalid
    sanitizeInput(input);
  catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({id:"sql_error",message:err});
    return;
  }

  dbCreateRowPromise(input)
    .then(result => {//Handle success})
    .catch(err => {res.status(500).json({id:"sql_error",message:err}})
}
```

As you can see I'm writting catch twice and both times I'm writing the same response 500 status and handling the catch in the same way. Is there any good way to combine this 2 catches in a single one?

Comment: These types of questions don't provide a **problem**. This belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @ProEvilz I don't believe so, code review wants running code, pseudo code doesn't really interest them.

Comment: @Icepickle This question is a 'how can I improve my code' question. It doesn't matter whether it's pseudo in this instance because the highlighted part is the use of catch & try blocks.

Comment: @ProEvilz Actually for me, it doesn't even look like functioning code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in your current way of writing the code, you are not returning anything, and any following statements will assume that everything went ok, as you are handling the `catch` already, and transform the response.

I think you could just rewrite your statement in the following way:

```js
function sanitizeInput( input ) {
  if (input % 2 === 0) {
    throw 'Cannot input even number';
  }
  return input;
}

function dbCreateRowPromise( input ) {
  return Promise.resolve(input);
}

function my_function( input ) {
  return Promise.resolve(input)
    .then( sanitizeInput )
    .then( dbCreateRowPromise );
}

// perfectly normall input
my_function(5)
  .then( out => console.log(out))
  .catch( err => console.log('error occured', err));
  
// errourness input
my_function(4)
  .then( out => console.log(out))
  .catch( err => console.log('error occured', err));
```

Just use the promises to build a chain of events, and let the error be thrown. In case it is not handled by the callee, the error will be shown in the console eventually.

Comment: I first chose a different answer as the accepted one but ended up looking at this answer several times because of it's provided working code, so decided to change the accepted answer to this one as it was by far the most useful to me. Thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you're encountering is a mixture of synchronous code, promises and async callbacks which have different error handling techniques.

One solution is to just do what you're doing, handle the different styles of errors individually, but this could get confusing and complicated. The other is to attempt to unify all such code into a single style, using simple abstractions to smooth them over.

I would personally attempt to normalize all of my calls as async callback style calls and then unify the error handling this way. For example it looks like you're using `express` middleware here, so I would pass all errors out and handle them in an error handler middleware.

```
import { auto, constant } from 'async'
const { assign } from Object

function sanitize (opts, callback) {
  const { input } = opts
  try {
    sanitizeInput(input)
    callback()
  } catch (err) {
    callback(assign(err, { status: 'sanitize_error', statusCode: 500 })
  }
}

function createRow (opts, callback) {
  const { santizie: input } = opts
  dbCreateRowPromise(input)
    .then(result => callback(null, result))
    .catch(err => callback(assign(err, { status: 'create_row_error', statusCode: 500 }))
}

function my_function(req, res, input, next) {
  const block = {
    input: constant(input),
    sanitize: ['input', sanitize],
    createRow: ['sanitize', createRow]
  }

  auto(block, (err, result) => {
    if (err) return next(err)
    res.status(200).json({ status: 'ok' }))
  })
}

function errorHandler(err, req, res) {
  res.status(err.statusCode).json(err)
}
```

Comment: I don't see any asynchronous callbacks in the OPs code. Why are you going back from promise to nodeback style?

Comment: I didn't either but the wrapping function `function my_function(req, res, input)` looks like an express function which does actually have an optional implied callback. You don't get very far into express before you start using the callback also. So it may not have been explicit in the question but I inferred that it was part of the broader answer.

Comment: I've always wrapped express so that it works properly with promise-returning router handlers :-)

Comment: I think normalizing the code as promises instead of callbacks is a totally legit option. The point is to unify them all to be the same style then use that. I personally find promises less desirable than callbacks once you have more than simple linear flow. The async library + callbacks is more elegant, imo.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider making sanitizeInput return a promise. Then you can write:

```
sanitizeInput(input)
.then(function(data)){
   return dbCreateRowPromise(input);
})
.then(function(data)){
   //success
})
.catch(function(error)){
   //all failures
})
```

I am assuming your functions return something - if not `data` would just be null

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `async`/`await` syntax for your function:

```
async function my_function(req, res, input) {
  try {
    input = sanitizeInput(input);
    let result = await dbCreateRowPromise(input);
    // handle result
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({id:"sql_error",message:err});
  }
}
```

Alternatively, make a promise for `sanitizeInput` so that you can use promise chaining and handle errors from it as a rejection.

```
var promise;
try {
  promise = Promise.resolve(sanitizeInput(input));
} catch (err) {
  promise = Promise.reject(err);
}
promise.then(input => 
  dbCreateRowPromise(input)
).then(result => {
  // Handle success
}).catch(err => {
  res.status(500).json({id:"sql_error",message:err});
});
```

or

```
new Promise(resolve =>
  resolve(sanitizeInput(input))
).then(input =>
  dbCreateRowPromise(input)
).then(…).catch(…);
```

or

```
Promise.resolve(input).then(sanitizeInput).then(dbCreateRowPromise).then(…).catch(…)
```